# Objects and Meshes not showing up on collections tab

Tags: objects

Hi non the new meshes that I add to my scene are in the collections tab could someone please help with it, I’m sorry if I’m missing something super obvious but I am a newbie and don’t really understand, Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hey, i think you have added your mesh to the mesh "Cube.001" via SHIFT+A in Edit Mode. If you want to make a separate object instead of adding this into an other mesh, go in Object Mode and hit SHIFT+A.

But you can also separate parts of meshes or merge them anytime. 

F.e - if you want to separate the door from the rest of the house, select a part of your door mesh, hit CTRL+L to select linked vertices and then hit P and select "Separate Selection".

But if you want to merge your door with the house again, select both of your objects and press CTRL+J.

Let me know if it was helpful.

Comment: Hi thank you so much! You were correct they were all merged together I didn’t know if you add an object while in edit mode they connect, thanks again much appreciated :)

Comment: You're welcome. I`ll just post the comment as answer so other viewers find it quick.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have added your mesh to the mesh "Cube.001" via SHIFT+A in Edit Mode. If you want to make a separate object instead of adding this into an other mesh, go in Object Mode and hit SHIFT+A.

But you can also separate parts of meshes or merge them anytime.

F.e - if you want to separate the door from the rest of the house, select a part of your door mesh, hit CTRL+L to select linked vertices and then hit P and select "Separate Selection".

But if you want to merge your door with the house again, select both of your objects and press CTRL+J. Let me know if it was helpful.